# substring with while loop

Tags: java

I want to read a text from a file. Every line should be split at 180 characters and then each line should be added to a table, but I get the error message "String index out of range -180".

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadAndWrite {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("xyz.txt"));

         String line = read.readLine();
         int len = line.length();

         System.out.println(len);

         int chaCount = 0;
         while (chaCount < len) {
             String line2 = line.substring(chaCount, 180);
             System.out.println(line2);
             chaCount += 180;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean `should be divided by 180 characters`?

Answer (score 0):

your Substring will work like this,

```
first loop: 
Substring(0,180);
second loop;
Substring(180,180);
//Error incoming
third loop
Substring(360,180);
```

you need to increase you´r ending or you will recive the error against and agains, because the Startindex has to be lower or equal to the endindex of the Substring

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
line2 = line.substring(chaCount, 180<len-chaCount? 180:len-chaCount);
```

You try to get 180 characters from `line` string that at some point would have less than 180 characters remaining.

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem in the lines of

line2 = line.substring(chaCount,180);

```
 System.out.println(line2);

 chaCount = chaCount +180;
```

for the first time, the system gets the output from 0 to 180. But the next time you are adding 180 with that and the output is empty. But when it tries that third time the error occurs. So dont add the chaCount or use another one variable to keep that value.